# Google Wallet postback for failed monthly charge

Tags: payment, android-pay

After 8 hours research I found that Google Wallet sends notification about subscription cancellation and doesn't send notification for monthly charges. Ok, I can live without this.

But customer's credit card can expire... What happens if Google can't get money from customer's credit card? Will Wallet cancel subscription or will it send notification to callback URL?
Does anyone have answer for this question?

I do not see information about this case anywhere.

One more issue is that I can't cancel subscription in my merchant center. Is this a feature or Google forgot to do this?

Comment: Ok, let this is a bad question, but I really can't find answers. Does minuser have answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you're referring to Wallet for Digital Goods:

- If Google can't obtain payment (or when users cancel), they'll [send you a failure postback](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6)
- [Canceling subscriptions in Merchant Center](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/3094698?hl=en&ref_topic=3092360)
  [image: sandbox merchant center screenshot]

Hth....

Comment: So Google Wallet cancels subscription if once can't obtain payment? This is not clear in documentation. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I can't understand why, but I do not see this button in my sandbox merchant console. And order details have different look.

Comment: @Nicolai can you include a screenshot?